# Find non-redundant, potentially overlapping, repeating strings with a python regex

Tags: python, regex, overlapping

Given a string with repetitive sequences between 2 and 5 letters in length, I want to find the maximal length, potentially overlapping substrings with a regex.

For non-overlapping patterns the following works:

```
>>> import re
>>> rpt_re = re.compile(r'(\w{2,5})\1+')
>>> s = 'xyzABCDEABCDEABCDEzyxDEFDEFxyz'
>>> for match in rpt_re.finditer(s):
...     print("{}: {}-{}".format(match.group(), match.start(), match.end()))
...
ABCDEABCDEABCDE: 3-18
DEFDEF: 21-27
```

But for the case below where two repeat units overlap this regex doesn't do what I want:

```
>>> s = 'xyzABCDEABCDEABCDEFDEFxyz'
>>> for match in rpt_re.finditer(s):
...     print("{}: {}-{}".format(match.group(), match.start(), match.end()))
...
ABCDEABCDEABCDE: 3-18
```

I would like to find a pattern that returns:

```
ABCDEABCDEABCDE: 3-18
DEFDEF: 16-22
```

I can see convoluted ways of acheiving this with and without regex's, but is there a single regex pattern that could do this without a bunch more code?

**Edit**

As may not be clear from the original description above, I am interested in finding start and end of repetitive substrings, so I want to mark the start and end of the `ABCDEABCDEABCDE` repeat, but am not interested in the internal repeats `BCDEABCDEA`, `CDEABDEAB` etc. which are fully contained within the `ABCDEABCDEABCDE` repeat.

However, in the second example 'xyzABCDEABCDEABC**DEFDEF**xyz' the `DEF` repeat is not redundant even though it overlaps the `ABDE` repeat because it extends beyond the `ABCDE` repeat.

An alternative approach with lookaheads is below, which gets close and would just require joining the overlapping repeat units:

```
>>> rpt_re = re.compile(r'(\w{2,5})(?=\1)')
>>> s = 'xyzABCDEABCDEABCDEFDEFxyz'
>>> for match in rpt_re.finditer(s):
...     rpt_length = match.end() - match.start()
...     print("repeat unit='{}': {}-{}".format(match.group(), match.start(), match.end() + rpt_length))
...
repeat unit='ABCDE': 3-13
repeat unit='ABCDE': 8-18
repeat unit='DEF': 16-22
```

...but I was hoping for something cleaner that didn't require code for joining overlapping matches together.

Comment: What makes that `BCDEABCDEA` is not a match you are interested in?

Comment: I would guess that it's impossible to get all overlapping sequences with just a single regex. As far as I know, the regex engine always processes the text from left to right, and never goes back. Also, as @JvdV points out, your expected result should include `BCDEABCDEA`, `CDEABCDEAB`, `DEABCDEABC` and `EABCDEABCD`.

Comment: Perhaps I haven't explained the problem properly, but I don't expect BCDEABCDEA,  CDEABCDEAB etc. as I am trying to find the beginning and end of any repetetive sequence between 2-5 letters long. Because BCDEABCDEA, CDEABCDEAB  etc. are contained within the ABCDEABCDEABCDE  repeat, I don't want to report them (as per the examples I give). However, the DEFDEF repeat extends past the ABCDE repeat (as well as  consisting of a different repeat unit) so I want to be able to report that overlapping but non-redundant repeat as an additional match.

Comment: Although having given some thought to this, I take your point, @mportes, that given the left to right processing I expect there is no single clean solution to this unless someone knows some regex magic I am unaware of